# Retrieve HTTP response code in WSO2 ESB/API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 API Manager and I want access to details of the client's incoming API request (into API Manager, for example, the HTTP method) as well the response from my API endpoint. I've followed the approach in the following document to write a custom mediator class which gets invokes on both the "In" (for the request) and "Out" (for the response) flows:

https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension

It seems I can get various bits of data that I need from the `MessageContext` that is passed into my mediator, but I'm struggling with getting the response code from my API endpoint. Is there a way to get access to the HTTP response itself (and all it's headers and other elements) from the `MessageContext`? I stumbled across the `PassThroughTransportUtils` class which has a `determineHttpStatusCode` method which I could call but I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

"HTTP_SC" property is stored in Axis2MessageContext, which can be accessed as below:

```
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext msgContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
    String httpStatusCode = (String) msgContext.getProperty(NhttpConstants.HTTP_SC);
```

can be null, if not set.

Comment: Do you know a way to set http status code in message context ? I'm getting null

Comment: Using the HTTP_SC HTTP properties in the in/out/fault sequence like    :     <property name="HTTP_SC" value="201" scope="axis2" />

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but here the value is hard coded. I want to get actual http status code coming form the response. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: <property name="httpStatusCode" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"  scope="default" type="STRING"/>          Now httpStatusCode holds the http status code.